# Appending cronjobs using ansible playbook

Tags: automation, cron, ansible, devops

I am new in ansible. I write a playbook for managing cron jobs using cron module on my control nodes. It worked and setup cronjob in crontab but remove all other previous cron job entries. Is there any way to append crontab entries rather than removing all previous entries. My ansible playbook is as below :

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:

  # Cron Change
    - cron:
        name: "First Entry"
        user: "root"
        minute: "30"
        hour: "6"
        job: "php /var/www/html/app/artisan cache:clear"

    - cron:
        name: "Scond Entry"
        user: "garima"
        minute: "40"
        hour: "5"
        job: "/bin/sh /scripts/rsync.sh"
```

Comment: What you have done above is appending cron jobs. The module does not remove existing entries. It will only replace or delete entries having the exact same `name` for the same `user` already managed with ansible. I strongly suspect there must be something else you are missing.

Comment: I had a same entry of "php /var/www/html/app/artisan cache:clear" but without name and when i run this playbook these two entries shown but my old entry removed.

Comment: And also when i use to add cronjab for new user it emoved all commented line which were present there already and showing only these new two lines.

Comment: @RahulAggarwal Make list of existing cronjobs and remove all entries in cron jobs for user `crontab -r`(you can add this with command module task) and create existing jobs using Ansible and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Ansible 2.9.12 that is being worked on now. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/71207